# Testing how many times a method was called from another method's return statement in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

Newbie to JS. I have this function. First, it checks for data in cache. If it's not there, it calls backend for this data and saves it to cache.

```
function doSomething() {

    return getCachedData()
        .catch(function() {
            return getData()
              .then(saveDataToCache);
        });
}
```

I need to test how many times cache and backend are called on the first and the second time the method doSomething is executed. Here is my test:

```
it('should test', function() {
        spyOn(this.service, 'doSomething').andCallThrough();
        spyOn(this.service, 'getCachedData').andCallThrough();
        spyOn(this.service, 'getData').andCallThrough();

        this.service.doSomething();
        this.$rootScope.$apply();

        expect(this.service.doSomething.callCount).toBe(1);
        expect(this.service.getCachedData.callCount).toBe(1);
        expect(this.service.getData.callCount).toBe(1);

        this.service.doSomething();
        this.$rootScope.$apply();

        expect(this.service.doSomething.callCount).toBe(2);
        expect(this.service.getCachedData.callCount).toBe(2);
        expect(this.service.getData.callCount).toBe(1);
    });
```

However, I am getting an error saying that call count for getCachedData and getData is always 0, both the first and the second time.

Changing *this.$rootScope.$apply();* to *this.$rootScope.$digest();* doesn't improve anything. I also tested it manually and everything seems to be working fine.

I also noticed that if I change the function doSomething as below then the counts for getCachedData are 2 & 2, which is correct.

```
function doSomething() {

    this.getCachedData();

    return getCachedData()
        .catch(function() {
            return getData()
              .then(saveDataToCache);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create an object. for example:

```
system_metrics ={
 cache_calls:0,
 backend_calls:0,
 reset_cache:function(){this.cache_calls=0;},
 reset_backend_calls:function(){this.backend_calls=0;},
 add_cache_call:function(){this.cache_calls++;}
 add_backend_call:function(){this.cache_calls++;}
}
```

in

```
function getCachedData(){
    //add this line
   system_metrics.add_cache_call();
}
```

in

```
function getData(){
    //add this line
   system_metrics.add_backend_call();
}
```

> I need to test how many times cache and backend are called on the first and the second time the method doSomething is executed

in

```
function doSomething(){
  if(system_metrics.cache_calls === 1){
     //the first time the method doSomething is executed
  }
  if(system_metrics.cache_calls === 2){
     //the second time the method doSomething is executed
  }
  if(system_metrics.backend_calls === 1){
     //the first time the method doSomething is executed
  }
  if(system_metrics.backend_calls === 2){
     //the second time the method doSomething is executed
  }
}
```

at anytime during execution.. lets say at the end of the day
you can now check `system_metrics.cache_calls` to give you total number of cache calls for the day.. thats if you never resetted the cache calls

at anytime during execution you can clear the number of cache calls with `system_metrics.reset_cache_calls`

**if your question is to check how many times cache was called
when doSomething runs for the first time or second time.**

**if your question is to check how many times backend was called
when doSomething runs for the first time or second time.**

add the following to your system_metrics
`do_something_calls`
`add_do_something_call`
`reset_do_something_call`
& add `add_do_something_call` to your `do_something function`
i think you get the picture

with this approach you can track any metric that you want anytime that you want to

Comment: Thank you. Great stuff. I think it's much more than I need. In other words, I need to write a unit test which will confirm that getCachedData() is called everytime doSomething() is called. And that getData is called only if there is no data cached.

Comment: The object contains all the data you will need for your test. the test becomes very simple to write.. so this is a test driven approach to your program. which makes the tests very simple >>> for example:: in your unit test.. 

when hasCachedData() && doSomething() // assertThat ( system_metrics.cachecalls ==1 && system_metrics. backend_calls =0)
when clearCache() && doSomething() // assertThat ( system_metrics.cache_calls ===1 && system_metrics. backend_calls === 1)